# Javascript Difference between prototype and call

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and got puzzled. An example over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) which has example as below:-

```
// define the Person Class
function Person() {}

Person.prototype.walk = function(){
  alert ('I am walking!');
};
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert ('hello');
};

// define the Student class
function Student() {
  // Call the parent constructor
  Person.call(this);// <---- Confusion
}

// inherit Person
Student.prototype = new Person(); //<---- Confusion

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

// replace the sayHello method
Student.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert('hi, I am a student');
}

// add sayGoodBye method
Student.prototype.sayGoodBye = function(){
  alert('goodBye');
}

var student1 = new Student();
student1.sayHello();
student1.walk();
student1.sayGoodBye();

// check inheritance
alert(student1 instanceof Person); // true 
alert(student1 instanceof Student); // true
```

Now, I am confused (`<----`) in these two lines. When I say `Person.call(this);`, this is simply stating to Inherit properties of Person class... Right?

Then what is this doing?

```
  // inherit Person
    Student.prototype = new Person(); //<---- Confusion
```

As per my knowledge, `.prototype` also inherits all properties?

Comment: I may sound very silly to people who are expert in javascript. But will feel much happy if you please comment and down vote.

Comment: this is different things you should learn more about call and apply methods of javascript this is will be very useful if you want learn this programing language

Comment: I don't see any reason for downvoting this question either. Prototypical inheritance is tricky to understand, and there's a lot of unclear and outright incorrect information out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain it, first let's remember how constructor functions work in JavaScript:

```
function Guide(a) {
    this.a = a;
}
Guide.prototype.q = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";

var g = new Guide(42);
console.log(g.q); // "Life, the Universe, and Everything"
console.log(g.a); // 42
```

When we do `new Guide(42)`, the `new` operator creates a new object and assigns it a *prototype* using the `Guide.prototype` property. Then `new` calls `Guide`, passing in that new object as `this`. `Guide` uses `this` to add properties to the new object that aren't on its prototype. Then the `new` expression completes and its result is the new object that it created.

When we look at `g.q`, since the `g` object doesn't have its *own* property called `q`, the JavaScript engine looks at `g`'s prototype, which (again) it got assigned when it was created. That prototype has a `q` property, and so the engine uses its value.

In contrast, when we look at `g.a`, the `g` object has its own property called `a`, and so the value is used directly.

With that foundation in place, let's look at `Student` and `Parent`:

```
function Student() {
  // Call the parent constructor
  Person.call(this);// <---- Confusion
}
```

When we call `new Student()`, within the call to `Student`, `this` is (again) the new object created by the `new` operator, which has `Student.prototype` as its underlying prototype. But the `Parent` function hasn't had a chance to do anything with this new object. So what that line does is give `Parent` a chance to do whatever it needs to do to new objects that it can't do via the prototype, like our `Guide` function earlier assigning to `this.a`. In technical terms, `Parent.call(this);` calls the `Parent` function, ensuring that `this` within the call to `Parent` is the value passed into `call` (which is, in this case, the `this` of the call to `Student` — e.g., the new object). If you're familiar with class-based languages, this is like doing `super();` (that's Java, but you get the idea) in a derived constructor: It gives the base constructor a chance to initialize the object.

```
// inherit Person
Student.prototype = new Person(); //<---- Confusion
```

Since `Student` is supposed to inherit from `Person`, what that code is doing is creating the prototype that will be assigned to objects created via `new Student`. The object it's creating is a `Person` object.

FWIW, that code isn't quite implementing the construction chain correctly (it's calling `Person` more often than it should [both when creating `Student.prototype` **and** when `Student` is called], and failing to set `constructor`).

The more correct way to create `Student`'s `prototype` property, if we're going to call `Parent` from within `Student`, looks like this:

```
function derive(child, parent) {
    function ctor() { this.constructor = child; }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor();
}

derive(Student, Parent);
```

That way, we get a prototype based on `Parent.prototype` but without calling `Parent`. It's an either-or: *Either* call `Parent` to create `Student.prototype`, *or* call `Parent` within `Student`, but don't do both. When building hierarchies with constructor functions, typically you want to call the parent from the child constructor, rather than when creating the child prototype. When using direct object inheritance (without constructor functions), of course you do it the other way.

If you're interested in inheritance in JavaScript, I've written a helper script called [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) you might want to look at, and in particular even if you don't use `Lineage`, [this discussion](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript) on its wiki page may be useful for understanding inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: @Crowder:- Just 3 words for you. You Are Awesome... Thanks a lot, lot and lottt...

Comment: @Idothisallday: LOL You're welome. I realized I didn't word the bit about what that code is doing wrong very well, so I reworded that after you accepted the answer. If you re-read starting with "FWIW" about two-thirds of the way down, that's where I fixed it. Best,